# Form not submitting anything

Tags: php, html, forms

Hi I'm new to web development. I have a change password form and I am trying to call the API but before that it doesn't seem that the form is submitting any data. Bellow is the form and the check that is used to check for the post but it is returning me nothing.

```
<form name="passwordForm" method="post">
<div class="password-form">
     <label>New Password:<span class="small-label"> Please enter at least 8 alphanumeric characters</span></label><input class="changepwd" type="password" name="newPassword1" required=""
      id="newPassword1" placeholder="Password"> <br>
<label>Re-type Password:</label><input class="retypepwd " type="password" name="newPassword2" required="" id="newPassword2" placeholder="Password">

     <button type="submit" value="Change Password" id="changePassword" class="buttonlink">Change
      Password</button>
    </form></div>

<?php 
if(isset($_POST['passwordForm'])){
       echo 'test';
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
    <form  method="post">
    <div class="password-form">
         <label>New Password:<span class="small-label"> Please enter at least 8 alphanumeric characters</span></label><input class="changepwd" type="password" name="newPassword1" required=""
          id="newPassword1" placeholder="Password"> <br>
    <label>Re-type Password:</label><input class="retypepwd " type="password" name="newPassword2" required="" id="newPassword2" placeholder="Password">

         <button type="submit" name="passwordForm" value="Change Password" id="changePassword" class="buttonlink">Change
          Password</button>
        </form></div>

    <?php 
    if(isset($_POST['passwordForm'])){
           echo 'test';
}
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
<form name="passwordForm" method="post">
<div class="password-form">
 <label>New Password:<span class="small-label"> Please enter at least 8 alphanumeric characters</span></label><input class="changepwd" type="password" name="newPassword1" required="" id="newPassword1" placeholder="Password"> <br>
 <label>Re-type Password:</label><input class="retypepwd " type="password" name="newPassword2" required="" id="newPassword2" placeholder="Password">

 <button type="submit" name="cmd_submit" value="Change Password" id="changePassword" class="buttonlink">Change
  Password</button>
</form></div>



<?php 
if(isset($_POST['cmd_submit'])){
   echo 'test';
 }
?>
```

Comment: no need to target the form name.. all you need to target is the name of the button... =)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<div class="password-form">
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
     <label>New Password:<span class="small-label"> Please enter at least 8    alphanumeric characters</span></label>
     <input class="changepwd" type="password" name="newPassword1" required="" id="newPassword1" placeholder="Password"> <br>
     <label>Re-type Password:</label>
     <input class="retypepwd " type="password" name="newPassword2" required="" id="newPassword2" placeholder="Password">

     <button type="submit" name="passwordForm" value="Change Password" id="changePassword" class="buttonlink">Change Password</button>
</form>
</div>

<?php 
if(isset($_POST['passwordForm'])){
       echo 'test';
}
?>
```